# What is the function of にも in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

I found this sentence on a manga, and I can't find its meaning for I don't understand the function of にも in this case:

> 勉強**にも**スポーツ**にも**それから恋愛か。

Comment: Can you tell us what this sentence is from or what the context might be?

Answer (score 2):

For example the question could have been "what are you taking interests in" with "in" standing for に, this would be a suggestion for the answer: "In learning and in sports and also relationships."

In this case you are summing up things you would use に after in a full sentence. 勉強に興味あります。

Answer (score 2):

In this context, 'にも' means 'as well as'

Comment: OP asks for the function but you gave a translation.

Comment: To be fair, the OP also said that they "*can't find its meaning*".

Comment: "In this context, 'にも' means 'as well as'" >> How is it different from 勉強**も**スポーツ**も** ?  What is the に doing here?