# What is the meaning of にも?

Tags: particle-に, particle-も

What does にも mean in this sentence?

> ムン大統領は、北朝鮮の選手たちにもオリンピックに出てほしいと考えています。

([full text here](https://www.reddit.com/r/NHKEasyNews/comments/7o9kap/01052018_%E9%9F%93%E5%9B%BD%E3%81%A8%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%AE%E9%96%93%E3%81%AF%E8%BB%8D%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%93%E7%B7%B4%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/))

I've found a topic where にも is discussed but it's not the same context and the explanations doesn't suit if I understand well: [What is the function of にも in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18769/what-is-the-function-of-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82-in-this-sentence)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us first get this usage of 「に」 down.

> 「Person + **に** + Verb in te-form + ほしい」

means:

> "(Someone) wants (Person) to (verb)."

The particle needs to be 「に」 there; No other will work.

So, adding a 「も」 should not make it any more difficult.

> 「Person + **にも** + Verb in te-form + ほしい」

thus means:

> "(Someone) wants (Person) **also** to (verb), too."

The "also" modifies (Person) here.

> "President Moon would like the North Korean athletes also to participate in the Olympics."

I hope you understand now that it is not possible to translate 「にも」 all by itself.